# Bike seen in Florence

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]I was in Florence Italy last week and saw this bike parked up. Can anyone help to identify what model this may be. Any information would be useful.

Comment: It is a generic (inexpensive) bike. There are many very similar sold with countless brand names. Why do you need to know exactly this one?

Comment: I just liked its simplicity for the city but couldn't see any Branding on the frame. Aesthetically very pleasing so wanted to to know more information. Thank you

Comment: These bikes are very popular now (it does look nice indeed!). You'll certainly find a couple that look almost the same or equally pleasing. They are typically sold for 300€ to 400€. Brand names are often added with stickers. Have a look at large bike stores and chains that sell Urban Bikes and City Bikes (I think these categories are used throughout continental Europe at the moment).

Comment: The best things to photograph are the whole bike (as shown) but from the right hand side, and a close up of any branding and logos.  Then if you have the chance to talk to the rider.  Everything else is harder and less authorative

Answer (score 3):

In the comments the point is made that there are several bike brands with bikes similar to this.

As an example (not an endorsement) here is one [sold by Olmo](https://www.olmo-bikes.eu/en/borgo-7v-man.html)
[image]

Comment: It's certainly very similar.  Minor differences in the mudguards and kickstand may not mean much and the chain cover (or whatever you call that semi-chaincase) is a good match, but the one the OP saw has a more old-fashioned looking front light (though no rear light and no apparent power source) and maybe a quill stem.  Perhaps it's a few years old (not too old: QRs)

Comment: Those front lights are available aftermarket as well. Anyway, in my opinion the distinguishing parts of the bike in question are thin head tube and rear fork that hint at steel and very thick down tube. That thing must be incredibly heavy.